# NgFor display n number of element

Tags: angular

I have time interval from 00 to 12 hours. I want to display a combo box option such as 00,01,02...12. How can I use ngFor in this case. There is no array or object declared. till index 12 I need to loop.

Answer (score 2):

```
*ngFor="let hour of hours"
```

```
hours = ['00', '01', '02', '03', '04', '05', '06', '07', '08', '09', '10', '11', '12'];
```

Comment: So,  Cant we fix i=12 n iterate like javascript do ?

Comment: Nope. `*ngFor` only works with arrays. You can simplify array creation usin TS in the componet's class and than iterate this array using `*ngFor` but besides that there is nothing `*ngFor` provides. Maybe eventually after final ...

Comment: I see. Then you have to create the array in the component.